# Broadcast service not getting called

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Using following code

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, BootUpReceiverRecall.class);
        sendBroadcast(i);

 <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="BootUpReceiverRecall"></receiver>


public class BootUpReceiverRecall extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
      // Restart service every 30 seconds
      private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 30;

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
      {
        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, BootUpReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Start 30 seconds after boot completed
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
        //
        // Fetch every 30 seconds
        // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
        service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);

        // service.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
        // REPEAT_TIME, pending);
      }
```

My BootUpReceiver never gets called. what wrong am i doing
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define it properly in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<receiver 
android:process=":remote"
android:name=".BootUpReceiverRecall" />
```

Take a look at "android:name" tag,
you need to add a dot(".") before the "BootUpReceiverRecall" if it is in the same package as your application,but if it is not you can simple use the full name like "app.package.receivers.BootUpReceiverRecall".